# Is there a way to grab an element by ID using httpwebrequest?

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I understand the basics of httpwebrequest and I'm not looking for any answers on web browsers. My previous method was done using webbrowsers but because of the lack of speed I have transferred over to httpwebrequest to speed up the process.

I have an id of an element that I would like to grab and use in an httpwebrequest but not sure where I would start with that.

Thanks

Comment: which element would you like to grab?

Comment: The name of the element is id="myname"

Comment: OK... cryptic, but I'll work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so to be clear: you can't grab an element from the `HttpWebRequest`, you have to get it from the `HttpWebResponse` (since this is where you get the HTML).

1. The `HttpWebResponse` provides you access to the response stream, which you can obtain by calling `GetResponseStream()`.
2. Instantiate an `HtmlDocument` (I recommend that you use the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library for that).
3. Use XPath to get the element by doing something along the lines of:
   `var nodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='myname']");`

I don't recall exactly, but there may also be a method to get an element by ID:

`htmlDoc.GetElementById("myname");`

Then you can iterate through the nodes and do whatever you need to do there.

Here is another example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshch/archive/2006/12/10/better-html-parsing-and-validation-with-htmlagilitypack.aspx